# how to create custom function to analyze tables in postgres

Tags: postgresql, function, greenplum

I'm trying to set up an function that analyzes tables on the weekends.

```
create or replace function public.sp_analyze(t text)
returns void as 
$$
BEGIN

  if to_char(current_Date,'dy') = 'fri' THEN
    --RAISE NOTICE '%', t;
    execute 'vacuum analyze' || t
  end if;
end;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Is there a way to execute my analyze command without throwing errors?

This is my error:

```
ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "end"
```

Comment: ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "end"

Comment: Please refer -> https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/C97A7021-C91B-41F3-8902-8CC41F5F5511%40gmail.com Quoting it:
You cannot use VACUUM in a function because it's not a transaction-safe operation.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the code, I suspect the error you're getting is about a non-existing relation.

The code `execute 'vacuum analyze' || t` is going to append the text that is passed in directly to the string.

Say that `t` is *foo*. The resulting string that will try to be `execute`d will be:

```
execute 'vacuum analyzefoo'
```

Which will yield an error of this form:

> ERROR:  relation "analyzefoo" does not exist

which I suspect is the type of error you were seeing.

If a space is added to the constant string, e.g.:

```
execute 'vacuum analyze ' || t;
```

this will be avoided.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

If you have a space in the command (which implies there's a space in `t`), then it's likely the *semicolon* missing on the `execute` statement leading to the syntax error. I've added that in my code snippet above.

Comment: Thanks but I have a space after the command. I just don't think it's taking my analyze statement.